# label setting to display updated text from right to left fixed at the end of string

Tags: c#, winforms, label

how to make label display updated text from right to left  fixed at the end of string, for example if usually update sequence looks like this:

```
               ⍈ hello
               ⍈ hello world
               ⍈ hi how are you
```

I want see it this way:

```
         hello ⍇
   hello world ⍇
hi how are you ⍇
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the label **`ContentAlignment`**

```
 label1.AutoSize = true;
 label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
 label1.Text = "#Hello";
```